# How to Convert Blueberry Muffin Recipe to Vanilla Muffin Recipe

Tags: muffins

I tried this recipe with good results.

http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/blueberry-coffee-cake-muffins-recipe/index.html

So I decided to make plain vanilla muffins using the same recipe except for adding blueberries. However, the texture was not the same - I am guessing this is because of the reduced moisture content from the missing blueberries.

Can someone please guide me as to what I should modify to make up for the reduced moisture (assuming that is the cause)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

Blueberries are [mostly water](http://www.ca.uky.edu/enri/pubs/enri129.pdf) (~74%) and your recipe calls for a pint of them. Blueberries are roughly spherical, so they will pack into a container with a [density of around 64%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing).

The recipe comes from a site in the US, so a [pint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pint) is, presumably, ~473ml. One thing I don't know is how much liquid blueberries transfer to the batter while they are cooking. If they transfer somewhere between 25% and 75% of their water content, then you are looking to **replace between 56ml and 168ml of liquid** (i.e. roughly between a quarter and three quarters of a US cup).

Since there is already milk in the recipe, you might just as well add extra milk.

Comment: Hi Chris, 

Thanks very much for this thorough response. Will try with additional milk.

Answer (score 1):

I LOVE Chris Steinbach's answer for it's thoroughness and while adding some quantity of liquid may improve the texture of this muffin, you can compare the liquid requirement for another non-fruited muffins to this one - particularly one that includes sour cream.

It also would be a good idea to bake a sample muffin to check for the proper texture before committing the whole batch.